# Testflight Workflow

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning, testflight

I am trying to understand the testflight App distribution workflow

1.
When a new tester wants to join my testing team - I ask them to create an account on test flight.

2.
Next they need to give me their device UUID so that I can add that UUID to the Distribution profile.
**Question** - What is the **best** way to get the UUID from the tester.  I do not want them to email it to me or give me the UUID over the phone. Since they have the testflight account and the iPhone - Can they upload their device UUID from the iPhone to the testflight account so that I can see that tester JohnDoe has UUID xyz - If so how?  What do they(The tester) need to run on the iPhone so that their UUID shows up when I (The App Developer) log into TestFlight.

3.
When I (The App Developer) have the newly Added UUID - I need to update the Distribution Provisioning Profile on my Apple Provisioning Portal with the new UUID - Save the updated Profile and then upload it back to Testflight.

**Question** -  Can this (adding the new UUID to a profile) be done via Testflight itself? - i.e. can Testflight update my Profile with a new UUID or can this only be done via the Apple provisioning portal and then be brought back into Testflight

There are similar questions but none answer exactly the two questions I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can always export device ID-s from your TestFlight users - exported file is 
ready to be directly imported in your Apple Developer Portal.

And you always get an automatic email when new user (or new device) is added to you
TestFlight account.

As for what is the best way: who knows, it's really a matter of choice.

2) No. TestFlight can't create a new provisioning profile with devices added.

You have to create it by yourself (Apple Developer Portal):

- add new devices to your developer account
- add this devices to provisioning profile
- regenerate and download provisioning profile
- update provisioning profile for TestFlight build (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14265876/653513)

Answer (score 2):

1. Best way to get UUID - is copy it from testers TestFlight profile when he will register device for testing.
2. You can update provisioning profile **only at Developer Apple** portal. **But you can update provisioning profile for existing build by pressing Update Profile on build page.**

Answer (score 1):

It's really much simpler:

1. Create team
2. Invite people by email
3. When they signup, they automatically email you their device UDID

Here's what TestFlight FAQ says about it: [How does it work?](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/829537-how-does-it-work-)

Step 4 is to manually add device id's into Apple site, generate new provision files, download and install, rebuild (hopefully using jenkins or something similar) and upload a new build to TestFlight (did I mention jenkins :))

Comment: When you say **rebuild** - Do you mean create a new IPA in Xcode?  My understanding is that just because you updated your profile with a new UUID - you do not have to create a new IPA - Is that correct?

Comment: You are right, guess I'm too used to "release often" process. You could just upload new provision file to TestFlight, which can then resign the old IPA file to include the new users.

Comment: How can we add "change log" or "Whats New" in new build uploaded over TestFlight? So that testers can check only those areas?

Answer (score 0):

1>Go to Project,Archive app.

2>In archive,click on distribute.

3>Click on save for enterprise or ad hoc deployment and save ipa file to your desktop

4>open https://testflightapp.com/dashboard/ and login

5>After login,click on upload your build button

6>Next click on drop your ipa file.Select .ipa file from desktop and upload it.

7>Selct provisioning profile by tick check mark and click update and notify button.

8>After clicking update and notify,Please click on share build button below update and notify.

9>Also you can see this share option by clicking permission on right hand menu.

10>After clicking share button,you need to provide your email id for showing testflight app in your mail inbox.

11>open test flight mail into your device and click on install button.

12>app automatically open testflight in your device,Please login with testflight,click on install profile button

13>After all click on app just you upload,click on install button. app will automatically install in your device.

Please tell me in case of any query regarding this.

Thanks

Comment: How can we add "change log" or "Whats New" in new build uploaded over TestFlight? So that testers can check only those areas? Otherwise we have to send this information manually over email, which doesn't seems good.

Answer (score 0):

try  TestFlight.top
Simple to invite testers
When a user requests to participate in your application test, you do not need to do any operation. Applicants only need to click on the download link in the page to directly download the test application. It is as simple as using the App Store